# Log to file using Serilog including last 10 other logs with each error log

Tags: c#, serilog, serilog-sinks-file

I would like to log using Serilog.  I want logging that only logs error or higher such that when the error is logged it includes the last 10 logs along with it.

I have made a proof of concept that works with the console.  Here is the code.  [Circular buffer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CircularBuffer) is a nuget package.

```cs
using CircularBuffer;
using Serilog.Core;
using Serilog.Events;

namespace ProminentMediaserilog;

public class ErrorWithRecentLogsSink : ILogEventSink
{
    private readonly CircularBuffer<LogEvent> _recentLogs; 

    public ErrorWithRecentLogsSink(int capacity)
    {
        _recentLogs = new CircularBuffer<LogEvent>(capacity);   
    }

    public void Emit(LogEvent logEvent)
    {       

        if (logEvent.Level < LogEventLevel.Error)
        {
            _recentLogs.PushBack(logEvent);
            return;
        }

        var recentLogs = string.Join(",", GetRecentLogs().Select(rl => GetLogMessage(rl)));
        var message = $"{GetLogMessage(logEvent)}{Environment.NewLine}Recent Logs: {recentLogs}";
        Console.WriteLine(message);    
    }

    private string GetLogMessage(LogEvent logEvent)
    {  
    return $"{logEvent.Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {logEvent.Level} {logEvent.RenderMessage()}{Environment.NewLine}";
    }

    public LogEvent[] GetRecentLogs()
    {
        return _recentLogs.ToArray();
    }
}
```

As you can see from the code when the log level is lower than error the logEvent is added to a Circular buffer which keeps the last 10 logs.  And when the log is error it logs the error and the last 10 logs from the buffer.

What I would like however is the same code to work but saving logs to a file not writing them to the console.  I could do similar to above and add my own logic to save the log message to a file but ideally I would like to achieve this using a sink that already exists such as [file](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file) so I can take advantage of all the file options it has such as creating a new file for each unit of time.

Is this possible to do and if so how do would you go about doing it?